# Saving an array of data from the Query with Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm trying to get an array with users that the currently logged in user is following, so that I can display them in the UICollectionView.

I've set up an activity class which contains pointers to the users (in "fromUser" and "toUser" columns). I tried then to get data for each user from the User class by using the includeKey method, which doesn't seem to work.

Here's my code:

```
 - (void)queryParseForFollowingUsers {

// Create query for users being followed by the current user
PFQuery *followingUsers = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"activity"];
[followingUsers whereKey:@"fromUser" equalTo: [PFUser currentUser]];
[followingUsers whereKey:@"activityType" equalTo:@"follow"];
[followingUsers includeKey:@"toUser"];

[followingUsers findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    // For each object from the query
    for (PFObject *followedUser in objects) {

        PFObject *userData = followedUser[@"toUser"];

        // Add object to the array of followedUsers

        [profilesArray addObject:userData];
        [profilesCollection reloadData];

    };

}];

NSLog(@"ARRAY RIGHT AFTER CREATION ######## %@", profilesArray);

}
```

The weird thing is that an array is not updated with any content when I check its status outside of the block, but when I NSLog it's current content in the loop it returns data just fine. The profilesArray object is defined in .h file.

Does anybody have any clue how to sort out this problem? I would be much obliged for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I cracked it:

```
 - (void)queryParseForFollowingUsers {

// Create query for users being followed by the current user
PFQuery *followingUsers = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"activity"];
[followingUsers whereKey:@"fromUser" equalTo: [PFUser currentUser]];
[followingUsers whereKey:@"activityType" equalTo:@"follow"];
[followingUsers includeKey:@"toUser"];

[followingUsers findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {

        // Create an empty array for comparison
        NSArray *emptyArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
        if ([objects isEqualToArray:emptyArray]) {
            [profilesArray removeAllObjects];

            // do something if there are no users followed by the current user

        } else {

            for (PFObject *followedUser in objects) {
                PFObject *userData = followedUser[@"toUser"];
                // Add object to the array of followedUsers
                [profilesArray addObject:userData];
                // Reload the collection view
                [self.profilesCollection reloadData];
            }
        }
    } else {
// Show the details of an error if it occurs
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"An error occured" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [error userInfo]] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    }

}];

 }
```